# Navigate to list view after button click In lighting

Tags: lightning, navigation, lightningnavigation

I want to navigate to list view on click of button in a case record. Even if the multiple cases tabs are open I would like to get focus to list view on button click in lighting. is this possible to do. Do any one have any idea on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this on a console tab?

Answer (score 0):

Its given in the documentation:

[Navigate To List](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToList/documentation)

in CMP:

```
<lightning:button type="button" name="NavigateToListView" onclick="{!c.navigateToListView}">Navigate</lightning:button>
```

in JS: (Generically to open listview)

```
navigateToListView: function (component, event, helper) {
    const navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToList");
    navEvent.setParams({
        "listViewId": '00B7F000001nIdaUAE', // hardcoded for example
        "listViewName": 'My Cases',
        "scope": "Case"
    });
    navEvent.fire();
},
```

If you are on a console tab and would like to open a listView for case as a primary tab then use: (Console related)

```
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.openTab({
        url: '/lightning/o/Case/list?filterName=00B7F000001nIdaUAE', // hardcoded for example
        focus: true
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

And if you already have your listview opened in the naviagtion item then use [navigation api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_focusNavigationItem.htm) to just focus back to the listview. (Console related)

```
    navigationItemAPI.focusNavigationItem().then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
    });
```